# How do I change a PictureBox's image?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, picturebox

I have a program in C# with a `PictureBox` object inside a `Form`. How do I change its picture? The pictures to chose from are in bin/Pics; they are jpeg in format, if that matters..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Assign a new [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) object to your `PictureBox`'s `Image` property. To load an `Image` from a file, you may use the [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx) method. In your particular case, assuming the current directory is one under `bin`, this should load the image `bin/Pics/image1.jpg`, for example:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Pics/image1.jpg");
```

Additionally, if these images are static and to be used only as resources in your application, resources would be a much better fit than files.

Comment: Of course, it depends on what you are going to do with the images. I prefer loading images from a `Stream` because the `FromFile()` method keeps the file handle open until the end of the applicaition life time. This can lead to unwanted side effects when you try to overwrite the image with a file that has the same name, for example.

Comment: Just to add to the above, I couldn't get my images to display then remembered that you need to add double \\ s for example;pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\bob\\Documents\\music.jpg");

Answer (score 4):

If you have an image imported as a resource in your project there is also this:

```
picPreview.Image = Properties.Resources.ImageName;
```

Where *picPreview* is the name of the picture box and *ImageName* is the name of the file you want to display.

*Resources are located by going to:  *Project --> Properties --> Resources*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ImageLocation` property of `pictureBox1`:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\MYAPP\Slider\Slider\bt1.jpg";
```